# Retrieving an attribute/value from the button with jquery

Tags: jquery, events, onclick

I'm trying to retrieve an attribute/value from each button whenever it's clicked by user but the code isn't working. (Just added html snippet for clarification)

```js
$(".btn-choice").on("click", function() {

  console.log("You clicked a button!!");

  var userBtnValue = ($(this).attr("value"));
  userBtnValue = parseInt(userBtnValue);
  
  console.log(userBtnValue);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card mt-1">
  <div class="card-header">
    <div class="card-body text-center">
      <h3 class="card-title">You Pick</h3>
      <button id="button-1" class="btn btn-danger btn-choice" value="1">
        <h1>1</h1>
      </button>
      <button id="button-2" class="btn btn-danger btn-choice" value="2">
        <h1>2</h1>
      </button>
      <button id="button-3" class="btn btn-danger btn-choice" value="3">
        <h1>3</h1>
      </button>
      <button id="button-4" class="btn btn-danger btn-choice" value="4">
        <h1>4</h1>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Does your button have a `value=` attribute that's an integer?  Perhaps you could include your HTML in a snippet (edit and click `[<>]`).   Are the for loop / compChoices / randomNum relevant to the question?

Comment: "*determine which button clicked*" - that will be `this` in the click handler.  It looks like your question is asking about retrieving an attribute/value from that button.  Please clarify the question title/body so that it's clear what you're actually asking about.

Comment: Just made some changes in the title and removed unrelated elements from the code. Hope it's a bit more clear now.

Comment: Thanks for adding details.  I've converted your code to an SO snippet and ... you can see it works fine.

Comment: Do you have any console errors (eg `$ not defined`)?  Have you included jquery?  Do you add the buttons after your run the code?  Either add the buttons via another script or run the code in the `<head>`?   Have you wrapped your code inside doc.ready?  `$(function() { ... your code ... });`

Comment: the code seems to be working. I don't see the problem

Comment: @AshikPaul  see comments above

Comment: Yes it's now working good. I believe the 'for loop' was causing the errors now that I've removed it, code is working. Thanks for helping!

Comment: You can update your question to provide further information - eg adding the `for` loop that you have in your actual code that's stopping it from working there.  (your original `for` loop would not have stopped it working as it was) - eg you have any callbacks / inline anonymous functions, it could be that `this` means something different inside the inner function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code instead of $(this).attr("value").

```
var userBtnValue = ($(this).val());
```

Did you lunch this code on Chrome?